# Call stop of Soundmanager Inline Player

Tags: javascript

Please help! I am not the most seasoned coder and I am trying to make a manual stop button for my Soundmanager Inline mp3. I've tried lots of things but can't figure out how to access inlineplayer.js to call a stop.

I am using this code within a div on my page:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.synapseunrest.com/soundmanager/demo/play-mp3-links/css/inlineplayer.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.synapseunrest.com/soundmanager/demo/flashblock/flashblock.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.synapseunrest.com/soundmanager/script/soundmanager2.js"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.synapseunrest.com/soundmanager/demo/play-mp3-links/script/inlineplayer.js" > </script>



<div id="sm2-container">
    <!-- SM2 flash goes here -->
</div>


<ul class="graphic">
  <li><a href="mp3/Centre for Indigenous Theatre.mp3">Centre for Indigenous Theatre</a></li>
  <li><a href="mp3/Fallen Angel.mp3">Fallen Angel</a></li>
  <li><a href="mp3/D'bi Young.mp3">D'bi Young</a></li>
  <li><a href="mp3/Haircuts.mp3">Haircuts By Kids</a></li>
  <li><a href="mp3/Hamlet.mp3">Hamlet</a></li>
  <li><a href="mp3/Kudelka.mp3">Kudelka</a></li>
  <li><a href="mp3/Lost Lyrics.mp3">Lost Lyrics</a></li>
  <li><a href="mp3/Next Sex.mp3">Next Sex</a></li>
  <li><a href="mp3/R Murray Shafer.mp3">R Murray Shaffer</a></li>
  <li><a href="mp3/Sarajevo.mp3">Sarajevo</a></li>
  <li><a href="mp3/Tallis Choir.mp3">Tallis Choir</a></li>
  <li><a href="mp3/Tallis.mp3" id="sound">Tallis</a></li>
   <li><a href="mp3/TDT Hidden Cameras.mp3" id="sound">TDT & the Hidden Cameras</a></li>
    <li><a href="mp3/The Real McCoy.mp3" id="sound">The Real McCoy</a></li>
    <li><a href="mp3/Final Fantasy.mp3" id="sound">Final Fantasy</a></li>

  </ul>
```

Ultimately I want to stop this player when I hide the containing div. I can't figure out how to call the javascript from the other document (inlineplayer.js) from within my primary page. I'm looking for something like soundmanager.stopSound() that I can append to my show/hide div actions, or even just make into a STOP button that will kill all sound coming from this player.

I based this player on this template: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/play-mp3-links/

I have a feeling I'm supposed to call from here: http://www.synapseunrest.com/soundmanager/demo/play-mp3-links/script/inlineplayer.js

But I have no idea how to do that!
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

since you embedded the *"inlineplayer.js"* there should be a javascript object named *"inlinePlayer"* in the global scope. you can use that line in your hide-div function:

```
inlinePlayer.stopSound(inlinePlayer.lastSound);
```

or even better - check if the Object exist and if a Sound has been played:

```
if(inlinePlayer){
    if(inlinePlayer.lastSound){
        inlinePlayer.stopSound(inlinePlayer.lastSound);
    }
}
```